# Update Manager doesn't show any updates

Tags: update-manager

I am running the Update Manager (in Ubuntu 12.04) for the first time in several months. When checking for updates, the Update Manager doesn't find any, and returns the following error message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download.
     They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What do I do to kick it up and running properly again?

Comment: From the URL in the error message I see you're running `natty` for at least the `extras` repository. It has become unsupported (End-of-life). Are you sure you're running Ubuntu 12.04? Please post the output of `cat /etc/issue` and `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: As per your queries: bash: cat/etc/issue: Filen eller katalogen finns inte (the document or catalogue does not exist)
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise

Comment: It appears you've performed an partly incomplete upgrade in the past. One or more repositories specified are not configured for your 12.04 release. Please share the output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list*` (now copy-paste literally as you appear to have lost a space in the previous command I posted) Output is long, so consider posting it online (e.g. paste.ubuntu.com)

Comment: Posted the result online at paste.ubuntu.com (http://paste.ubuntu.com/1464328/) where you apparently can view it. I am sorry I am not - yet - familiar with community norms and tools. Thankful for your assistance!

Comment: By the way, the proper result of the cat /etc/issue prompt was: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have at least one repository still configured for `natty` (11.04). This may indicate that a previous upgrade has not taken this into account or that you've altered the `sources.list` file yourself and didn't change it when upgrading.

From the comments I can determine that it's just one line that is not configured for `precise`, the 'official' Ubuntu extras repository. Now the best thing to do is to fix this line to use `precise` instead. Below is just one way of doing this.

1. Open a terminal.
2. Enter the command

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
3. Locate the line containing

   ```
   deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
   ```
4. Change `natty` to `precise`, so the line becomes

   ```
   deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
   ```
5. Save and close the editor.
6. Run a manual update of the package lists:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

This should output without errors and your update manager should work again.

Comment: Done! I think it fixed the problem, as my UM now says that all software and package information is updated. Thanks Gert - with my best holiday wishes for you and yours.

Comment: It is still weird that you don't have new updates in several months. Anyway, consider marking the answer as accepted and/or upvote it rather than a "thank you" comment. :)

Comment: I agree with the weirdness. As you can see, I have pasted (http://paste.ubuntu.com/1464395/) the complete result of the gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list command. There are several other lines containing "natty" other than the one where I changed natty to precise. Do I need to change anything more there?

Comment: @ThomasG No, those ones are commented out; not used.